# to get the integer value after : and subtract it from the next value

Tags: python-2.7

I have text file like this and I need to get the integer from each line like 246012 and subtract it from the next line's integer using python

```
[739:246012] PHYThrad: DSPMsgQ  Received: msg type is[130] and SFNSF [14996] [SFN:937 SF:4]
[739:246050] START of MACThread:receved msg type[47]
[739:247021] PHYThrad: DSPMsgQ  Received: msg type is[130] and SFNSF [14997] [SFN:937 SF:5]
[739:247059] START of MACThread:receved msg type[47]
[739:248013] PHYThrad: DSPMsgQ  Received: msg type is[130] and SFNSF [14998] [SFN:937 SF:6]
[739:248053] START of MACThread:receved msg type[47]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
with open('myfile.txt') as a:
    a = a.readlines()
    nums = [int(lines[lines.find(':')+1:lines.find(']')]) for lines in a]
    result = [y - x for x, y in zip(nums, nums[1:])]

print result
```